# Save Firebase notification in android app

Tags: android

i have 2 problems in my android app i need solutions for them please

first problem , when the users taps on the Firebase notifications they can see them but when he close the app and open it again , the notifications message disappear so how can i save incoming notification message in the app in only one day and then it can disappear ?

second problem , i need to let the users copy texts in the app into there phone , Thanks a lot .

here is the display activity code

```js
package sanstephano.youth;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import static android.R.attr.key;

public class DisplayPush extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Title,Message;
    Button goApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_push);

        goApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but6);
        Title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        Message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_message);

        if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet())
            {


                if (key.equals("title"))
                    Title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));

                else   if (key.equals("message"))
                    Message.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));

            }


            }


                onButClick();


    }

    private void onButClick() {
        goApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DisplayPush.this,Screen2.class));

            }
        });
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle it.

1) handle by online database. Like call the SP and get all the pending notification and they ll save the data.

2) other is handle on our side. Create database and store all the relevant information on arrival of the notification.
So when user visit that page again at that time query our local database to get all notification back and redirect them to the relevant page.

Comment: could you please guide me with tutorials in any way of these two ways ??